Use VBA to update certain ranges and not add all entries again
I need to make a login macro for dialy visits, but every time I run it, it updates the existing entries and I only need to update the else conditional added for the last 3 values.
I need to check if current user is already created, to skip and add device entry only. If not, add it.
This is the macro I made.
Sub LogToDatabase()
    Dim loginSheet As Worksheet
    Dim databaseSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastLoginRow As Long
    Dim lastDatabaseRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    ' Define sheets
    Set loginSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Login Tab")
    Set databaseSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

    ' Find the last row with data in the login sheet
    lastLoginRow = loginSheet.Cells(loginSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Find the last row with data in the database sheet
    lastDatabaseRow = databaseSheet.Cells(databaseSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Copy each new row from the login tab to the database
    For i = 2 To lastLoginRow
        ' Check if the record already exists in the database
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(databaseSheet.Range("D:D"), loginSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value) = 0 Then
            ' Copy user information from Login Tab to Database
            databaseSheet.Cells(lastDatabaseRow + 1, 1).Value = loginSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value ' NOMBRE
            databaseSheet.Cells(lastDatabaseRow + 1, 2).Value = loginSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value ' APELLIDO
            databaseSheet.Cells(lastDatabaseRow + 1, 3).Value = loginSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value ' TIPO DE DOCUMENTO
            databaseSheet.Cells(lastDatabaseRow + 1, 4).Value = loginSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value ' DOCUMENTO
            databaseSheet.Cells(lastDatabaseRow + 1, 5).Value = loginSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value ' TELEFONO
            databaseSheet.Cells(lastDatabaseRow + 1, 6).Value = loginSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value ' DIRECCION
            databaseSheet.Cells(lastDatabaseRow + 1, 7).Value = 1 ' Total Visits
            databaseSheet.Cells(lastDatabaseRow + 1, 8).Value = Now() ' Last Visit Date
            databaseSheet.Cells(lastDatabaseRow + 1, 9).Value = loginSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value ' DISPOSITIVO

            lastDatabaseRow = lastDatabaseRow + 1
        Else
            ' If record exists, update Total Visits and Last Visit Date
            Dim existingRow As Long
            existingRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(loginSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value, databaseSheet.Range("D:D"), 0)
            databaseSheet.Cells(existingRow, 7).Value = databaseSheet.Cells(existingRow, 7).Value + 1 ' Increment Total Visits
            databaseSheet.Cells(existingRow, 8).Value = Now() ' Update Last Visit Date
            databaseSheet.Cells(existingRow, 9).Value = databaseSheet.Cells(existingRow, 9).Value & ", " & loginSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value ' Append Device Use
        End If
    Next i
End Sub



You can use Match alone here, without needing Countif:
Sub LogToDatabase()
    Dim loginSheet As Worksheet, databaseSheet As Worksheet
    Dim dbRow As Range, i As Long, m As Variant, doc

    Set loginSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Login Tab")
    Set databaseSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

    ' Copy each new row from the login tab to the database
    For i = 2 To loginSheet.Cells(loginSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        doc = loginSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value 'documento
        m = Application.Match(doc, databaseSheet.Range("D:D"), 0) ' Try to find a match in the database
        
        If IsError(m) Then ' `m` will be an error value if no match was found in ColD
            ' Find the next empty row in the database
            Set dbRow = databaseSheet.Cells(databaseSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow
            'Copy NOMBRE,APELLIDO,TIPO DE DOCUMENTO,DOCUMENTO,TELEFONO,DIRECCION (first 6 cells)
            dbRow.Cells(1).Resize(1, 6).Value = loginSheet.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 6).Value
        Else
            Set dbRow = databaseSheet.Rows(m) 'the matched row (for update)
        End If
        'same for new/updated
        dbRow.Cells(7).Value = dbRow.Cells(7).Value + 1  ' Increment Total Visits
        dbRow.Cells(8).Value = Now()                     ' Last Visit Date
        With dbRow.Cells(9)
            .Value = .Value & IIf(Len(.Value) > 0, ",", "") & _
                     loginSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value ' Append Device Use
        End With
    Next i
End Sub

